# Placing controls on datagrid with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, wpfdatagrid

I need a custom control element. I prototyped it and here it is on the picture. I think it is pretty self-explanatory. Could anyone suggest me how to organize it? I am not a WPF guru so if it will be working solution I'll better use it instead of doing by myself.

Sadly I can't post image, so it is here: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/521/control1.png/

Should I use datagrid with custom templates?

1. If so my question is how to populate row cells with custom contols and how to handle events on this controls to operate the RowId number?
2. How to apply custom templates for any individual cells? I found articles where templates applyed only for entire grid or column.

If anyone can help with this I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: This looks like a treeview and not like a datagrid to me

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use a `TreeView`.  If your classes are already grouped properly ,you can then use `HierarchicalDataTemplates` to define how the `TreeView` works with each type.  This will involve templates and triggers.  Really, this will be mostly xaml, with very little event coding.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. XAML is kind of complicated but I thought it should be the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750972%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in grouping mode (with styles and templates)to accomplish this. Here are few samples doing similar to what you want to achieve -

> [ListView with grouping (In GridView mode)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/atc_avalon_team/archive/2006/03/15/551721.aspx)
>
> [Empty groups in WPF ListView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33986/Empty-groups-in-WPF-ListView)
>
> MSDN is also having one sample for this -
>
> [ListView Grouping Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771309%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)